# How can I set property value use another property without use new() method?

Tags: c#, http-post

I want to initialize an object not by using the NEW() method but by the following parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateXXX([FromBody] MyObj myob)
        {
            ...
        }
```

But the object have props that get set value by another props:

```
public class MyObj 
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string month{ get; set; }
        decimal _price { get; set; }
        public decimal price
        {

            get
            {
               
                if (month< new DateTime(2019, 9, 1))
                {
                    _price = 50
                }
                return _price ;

            }
            set
            {
               
                if (month>= new DateTime(2019, 9, 1))
                    _price = value;


            }
        }
      

    }
```

I know the option of init the month in the constructor, but can I do it in the HttpPost request?

Comment: Which new do you want to avoid? The datetime? What is the res variable?

Comment: From : public long id { get; set; } To : public long id = 123;

Comment: I had a mistake with the class name, sorry,I fixed now.

Comment: I want avoid from the new() of MyObj class

Answer (score 1):

Try use readonly member.

in your case:

```
decimal readonly _priceReadOnly { get; set; }

decimal _price { get; set; }
```

and init it like _price

and get the value from the raedonly if the regular is null